# Bug ao auto organizar Javascript no snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Caso use o editor de fragmentos do site para editar um código em *JavaScript* que faça uso do [operador lógico para atribuição nula](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)...

```js
const a = { duration: 50 };

a.duration ??= 10;
console.log(a.duration);
// expected output: 50

a.speed ??= 25;
console.log(a.speed);
// expected output: 25
```

e ao pressionar o botão organizar:

[image: botão organizar no "trecho de código" (Stack Snippet)]

```js
const a = {
  duration: 50
};

a.duration ? ? = 10;
console.log(a.duration);
// expected output: 50

a.speed ? ? = 25;
console.log(a.speed);
// expected output: 25
```

... o operador `??=` não é compreendido pelo *auto organizar* e é separado por um espaço `? ?=` forçando um erro de sintaxe.

Num fonte com poucas linha é só um pequeno incomodo, em fontes maiores isso pode se tornar uma dor de cabeça já que o *snippet* ao informar erros no *JavaScript* não informa corretamente o número da linha em que ocorreu o erro.

Comment: Eu uso bastante pra `React`, dá muito problema nas `tags` e desconfigura todo `js`. Realmente é um problema muito antigo e afeta ao meu ver muitos tipos de código. Que pena! Fora que é muito, muito limitado, deveriam mudar...

Comment: @novic deveriam mudar mesmo. Eu sinto que o site está congelado no tempo no quesito multimeios. Cito como exemplo o editor de código do *VSCode* o [Monaco](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) está disponível online sob licença *MIT* fornecido pela *Microsoft* e poderia ser integrado a interface do SO, pelo menos na versão desktop.

Comment: Verdade Augusto falou tudo, está muito atrasado mesmo e tem ferramentas disponível e acho que não há interesses de ninguém mudar

Comment: Apenas para acompanhamento, isso foi reportado no Metão também: [JavaScript code snippet Tidy function injects a separating space into the null coalesce operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355267/818993)